# Best way to run volatile containers on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, containers

I have scripts that collect data all the time on Google Cloud VMs, but there are times when I have more or less data to collect, so I need to volatile and automatically allocate CPU and memory so I don't spend so much money. Searching I saw that the best way is to create container and orchestrate them correctly, google offers Kubernetes, Cloud Run or Google Compute Engine, which is the simplest and best for this problem? Or if there is another platform that solves it better, which one?

Ps. I'm new in Cloud Computing, sorry if I made a mistake or said something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely forget about GCE ( compute engine ),

It remains GKE or Cloud run, you have to choose depending on your needs, here is the best article I be found:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/when-to-use-google-kubernetes-engine-vs-cloud-run-for-containers

[image]

However2 if you choose to use k8s, you can manage resources within the deployments tank manifests in the "resources" section. The request would be the minimum allocated resources to your deployment and the limits will be the maximum resources the deployment can use. You may play with this maybe.

Comment: I tried running it through Cloud Run, but I need to adapt my script to run as a Rest API with a domain right?

Comment: What is in your script?

Comment: The script makes Rest requests, with the acquired data we use our libs to manipulate and save in our DB. So I can't modify the script to act as a flask/unicorn server

Comment: According to your questions and to what you are saying I suggest you to adapt it for sure !!!